# Odd values printed when dereferencing the end iterator of a vector

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have a vector storing {1,2,3,4,5}. I tried to print `*(vec.end())` and got back the result 6. I don't know how to explain this. Similarly, calling `vec.find(500)` gave the result 6. Why am I getting this number?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<set>
#include<map>
int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::set<int> set1(a,a+sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));
    for (std::set<int>::iterator itr=set1.begin();itr!=set1.end();++itr){
        std::cout << *itr << std::endl;
    }
    //std::pair<std::set<int>::iterator, bool> ret;
    //ret = set1.insert(1);
    //std::cout << *(ret.first) << "first;second" << ret.second << std::endl;
    std::set<int>::iterator itr1 = set1.begin();
    set1.insert(itr1,100);
    std::advance(itr1,3);
    std::cout << *itr1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(set1.find(500)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(set1.end()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `Then I tried to print *(vec.end())`  You're lucky your program reached that far.  It is undefined behavior to dereference the `end` iterator.

Comment: @daydayup can you share some of your code?

Comment: I added some of my code on "set" instead of vector, it is the same thing. See the last two lines. Thank u. Sorry it is messy because I am exercising other things on it.

Comment: You can get the last element with `vec.back()`, by the way.

Comment: @daydayup: If the question is about vectors and `vec.end()`, how come ther are no vectors and no `vec` in the code you provided?

Comment: sorry I changed my codes to set later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vec.end()` does not point to the last element, but somewhat "behind" the last one.

You are not accessing the last element in the vector. Instead you are dereferencing an "invalid" iterator, which is undefined behaviour and turns out to be an invalid index in the vector in this case.

`vec.find` returns the end iterator if the searched element can not be found.

Comment: That means vec.find() could cause the program to crash if the searched element is not found?

Comment: @daydayup: Only if you dereference the returned iterator unconditionally

Comment: `vec.find()` returns the end iterator, which is well defined. What could cause a crash is dereferencing that iterator.

Comment: I see. So if I don't want the program to crash, i need to check if the returned iterator is the end iterator, instead of dereferencing it directly?

Comment: Exactly. If the iterator equals the end iterator, the find function has not found the element you asked for.

Comment: You have to do *something* sensible if you search for an element that doesn't exist, and accessing the non-existent element certainly isn't it.

Comment: Hey can I add a question? I am new learner to stl and what can iterator do for us, besides fetching values (means dereferencing it)

Comment: @daydayup Compare it to another iterator, increment it, decrement it, use it as an insertion point, delete its referent, and many other things depending on the type of iterator it is.

Answer (score 6):

This line invokes undefined behavior:

`std::cout << *(set1.end()) << std::endl;`

It is undefined behavior to dereference the `end()` iterator.  Thus anything can be expected.

Comment: likewise for the line prior, btw.

Comment: Would still be interesting, why it prints 6 though.

Comment: @MikeMB There is no definitive reason for why `6` prints. That is the very essence of *undefined* behavior.

Comment: @MikeMB `Would still be interesting, why it prints 6 though.`  In debug mode for Visual Studio 2013, a scary dialog box is displayed announcing that you've dereferenced the `end()` iterator.  For a release build, `-1163005939` is printed, not 6.  See what undefined behavior can do?

Comment: @WhozCraig: Undefined behavior means, that the standard doesn't require any specific behavior which in turn means, that the compiler can do what it wants and still be called 'Standard compliant'. That doesn't mean, that for most instances of UB, there isn't a (sometimes very complicated) reason, that explains that particular behavior. `6` being the follow up of  `1,2,3,4,5 ` it is unlikely, that this is just any random value that happenes to be at that memory location.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Both of those realizations of undefined behaviors seem logic to me: The first is a debugging functionality of Visual studio, the second seem like some random value stored at the memory location one past the last elment (at whatever memory location that is). Now I know, that UB means anything can happen. But if your program would actually order a pizza upon encountering UB, you would probably still asking yourself, how this could actually happen.

Comment: @MikeMB "...there isn't a (sometimes very complicated) reason, that explains that particular behavior." that very complicated reason lays outside definitive behavior of the standard, and as such i honestly have no real interest, nor time, chasing goblins. I'd enjoy the pizza, fix the UB, and move on.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You know, I'm not the OP? I also didn't ask you to explain to me anything. I just stated that I find that specific realization of UB curious. If you don't, that's fine with me.

Comment: @MikeMB Likewise on both counts back. I can certainly understand your curiosity of why, after invoking UB, a pizza mysteriously shows up at the door. Maybe it *was* the UB code. Then again, *maybe* a roommate or friend ordered it and it has nothing to do with invoking UB (which was somewhat my point; attributing UB to a definitive result). My wife says thanks for the idea for dinner btw, as do I =P.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ containers, the `end` iterator gives an iterator one past the end of the elements of the container. It's not safe to dereference the iterator because it's not actually looking at an element. You get undefined behavior if you try to do this - it might print something sensible, but it might just immediately crash the program.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Never try to use `end()` of any stl container because it does not point to a valid data. It always point to a chunk of memory that is located after the actual data. Use `end()` only to check whether your iterator has come to end or not. This image clearly explains where `end()` is located in default (non-reversed) range:

[image: STL Container's begin and end]

Comment: I recommend you to read [Jossutis C++11 Standard Library](http://www.cppstdlib.com/). It will help you much as it did for a lot of people.

Comment: thank you I will check that out later after I grab the basics.